# How to force spring-boot to refresh resources?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-boot, spring-rest

I would like to control a camera using a web app.
The client have to ask to the server for a preview immage.
I'm saving the preview immage in :

```
src

└── main

    └── resources

         └── public

             └── img
```

When i try to get a new preview i get the old picture (but the new one have alredy overrided that), after refreshing the resource folder manually from the IDE, i get the right-one.
Am I putting in the wrong folder the image? There is some way to make this refresh automatic ?

Comment: I think it is totally depend on your IDE, because in some IDE Tomcat refresh your web app on each server side change, or if it is not refreshing automatically then you need to clean or refresh it

Comment: can you add some info about how `spring-boot` applies to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can control in which directories Spring Boot is going to look for static resources. You are updating the `sources` of your project so there's no way Spring Boot is going to look there by default: when you run an app, the only thing the process can "see" is the classpath.

You can teach Spring Boot to look elsewhere. Let's assume for the sake of this example that you want to save your resources in `/Users/foo/data`, add the following to your configuration:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/,file:/Users/foo/data
```

If you're saving a `foo.png` in `/users/foo/data` then it will be available at the root of your app (i.e. `http://localhost:8080/foo.png`). If the resources can be located at several locations, make sure to put the directory with the most recent image first in the list above.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all for your responses, i solved the probelm by reading the bytes the new immage-file an returning them with `ResponseEntity <byte[]>`.